# MSTest.exe gives assembly or module not found warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, dll, mstest

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution with a C# project and a test project which references the output of the C# project. The test project runs fine in Visual studio.

But if I run it with MSTest.exe in the Developer command prompt:

`MSTest.exe /testcontainer:mytest.dll`

it fails giving lots of warnings like:

> Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Extended.Query' directly or indirectly
>   referenced by the test container '(path of mytest.dll)' was not found.

I dont think Visual Studio is copying the referenced dlls which are not part of the solution.

What is the solution to this ? how do i run my test suit with MSTest.exe

Comment: I had a similar issue and got the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15133291/914033 He proposes to use vstest.console.exe instead of mstest.exe, and it worked for me!

Comment: I wonder how it can be a warning that an assembly or module is not found. Shouldn´t it be an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can reference assemblies from GAC
2. You can specify what files should be deployed alongside your compiled test assembly before tests are run with `DeploymentItemAttribute` on test method.

Comment: Thanks alex. But can you please elaborate on the 2nd point. Since I have a lot of references missing, i cannot GAC every singele reference.

Comment: In case this is of interest, I had an issue with a *specific* assembly not found and the accepted answer to this question helped me solve it: [EntityFramework.SqlServer not deployed in web publish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499148/entityframework-sqlserver-not-deployed-in-web-publish?lq=1).